# Centering text in a <td> column on a PHP SQL display

Tags: html, css

I have a table which displays data via SQL using php. The issue is that because the second column is a picture (col name "thumbsrc"), the first column's text (col name "photosrc") is not centering itself and stays on the top.

[image]

```
                <table class="table table-hover spacer">
                  <thead align="center" class="strong">
                    <td>NAME</td>
                    <td>PHOTO</td>
                    <td></td>
                  </thead>

                  <?php foreach($lstProperty as $rowProperty) { ?>
                    <tr align="center">

                      <td>
                        <?php
                          echo($rowProperty['photosrc']);
                        ?>
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <img src="../img/_uploads/lease/thumbs/<?php echo $rowProperty['thumbsrc']; ?>.jpg" class="w-10">
                      </td>

                      <td>
                        <img src="img/icon-remove.png"></a>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
                </table>
```

im trying to center the first column:

```
                      <td>
                        <?php
                          echo($rowProperty['photosrc']);
                        ?>
                      </td>
```

i attempted:

```
 <td style="margin: 0 auto;">

 <td style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
```

also tried bootstrap classes:

```
 <td class="my-auto">
```

None of those centers the text. Would like some help on the correct working code.

Comment: add `text-align:center` or `vertical-align:middle` to your my-auto class depending on which way you want to centre it

Comment: `align="center"` centers horizontally, you'd want `valign="middle"` to center vertically. `valign` is obsolete though, you should use CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Deprecated_attributes

Comment: How is this related to PHP after all?

Comment: tried the manual "style" to check if the suggestion works. there seems to be no effect: <td style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; text-align:center;">

Comment: I would recommend not writing inline CSS-though. Just give the column a class and set the style in your .css-file instead.

Comment: We still don't really know if you want vertical or horizontal alignment. You can still try to inspect the element in the browser and see if your change conflicts with used CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Centering the row via the align attribute is not recommended due to [missing support in HTML 5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_tr_align.asp). Use CSS instead.

To center text horizontally, either use `<td align="center">My Text</td>` or CSS:
`<td style="text-align: center;">My Text</td>`. [CSS text-align property](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

For vertical alignment, you can use the CSS property [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) with the value `middle`.

I.e., you should use

```php
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <?php
       echo($rowProperty['photosrc']);
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: It's not supported in HTML 5. I will edit my Answer accordingly and state that centering should not be done via the align attribute, but using CSS instead.
You're right that my statement was misleading here and it depends on the desired layout.

Comment: Your edit made it much clearer... :-) Personally, I would rather recommend setting a class and then set the style in the .css-file instead.

Answer (score 0):

The table cells has default vertical align to center. The parent classes might override the default. So you can force it again using inline style:

for vertical centering:

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle">
```

for horziontal centering:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
```